# ASP.Net 4.0 on IIS6 vs IIS7

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, asp.net-4.0

I am trying to convince my boss to upgrade a couple web app servers from Win 2003 to Win 2008 so I can utilize ASP.Net 4.0 on IIS7. I am also trying to get our SQL Server 2000 upgraded to 2008 so I can use Linq2SQL in VS2010 plus a bunch of other reasons.

But the boss is experiencing sticker shock now that I have told him what it all costs. So I guess I have to possibly cut back some where.

My question is what are the benefits of ASP.Net 4.0 on IIS7 over ASP.Net 4.0 on IIS6 or are there any real benefits?

Comment: You should read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-integration-with-iis).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to specifically pitch the benefits relative to .NET 4?

The security, management, and pipeline benefits of IIS7 on Server 2008 seem like an easy enough sell over IIS6 on Server 2003.

Comment: not really, we are talking about bean counters so it's all geek to them. If I cannot get them to approve the full upgrade then I may just opt for the SQL 2008 upgrade and run .Net 4.0 on the 2K3 servers under IIS6